# WebApi Authentication on LocalIIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I've a problem I can't resolve and you probably can help me. Basically i have two different projects, one of them a ASP.NET MVC and the other one a ASP.NET WebApi, both with Windows Authentication and they are working fine on IIS Express. My problem is when i change to Local IIS. When i change the both projects to Local IIS and i try to connect the MVC project with the WebApi project my User.Identity.Name is the IIS Pool User and not my Windows User.

This is how I'm invoking the WebApi Project.

```
private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
{
Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
});

_client.BaseAddress = new Uri(UrlHelper.GetUrl());
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = _client.PostAsJsonAsync(UrlHelper.GetUrl(_controller, action), input).Result;

if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var response = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TReturn>().Result;

return response;
}
```

Can you help me please?

Thank You s much

Comment: when you open IIS, double click on Authentication is Windows Authentication enabled or Disabled? is Anonymous Authentication Enabled or Disabled.. under application pools, for the user what is the name of the Identity when you double click Advanced Settings..? is it Anonymous or does it have your domain\elevateduser name?

Comment: WIndows Authentication Enabled, Anonymous Authentication disabled and ApplicationPool Identity is LocalSystem

Comment: you need to try it with an elevated user id